# how to get the status of a submit button inside a form in jsp from the same page?

Tags: jsp

I am using a submit button to navigate to some other page inside a form

```
<form action = "dummy.jsp" method="POST">
    <label for="disabledInput" class="control-label">Item Id</label>
    <input type="text" value=<%=downloadHelper.getFileName()%> name = "fileSelect" id = "fileSelect"/>
    <input type="hidden" name = "storeSelect" value = <%=downloadHelper.getStoreName()%> /> </br></br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="Download" value="Download">Download</button>
    <a href="/index.jsp" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>
</form>
```

How do I check weather the `Download` button is clicked or not in the current page. I can check it from `dummy.jsp` with the snippet:

```
if(request.getParameter("Download") != null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should [avoid scriptlets](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/code-convention-138726.html) and use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) and [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) instead.

With EL you can simply use a ternary expression, like:

```
<button ${empty param.Download ? '' : 'disabled="disabled"'} />
```